# matrix multiplication insider a data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I need to do matrix multiplication inside a data.table. Like this

```
DT1 <- data.table( x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

DT2 <- data.table(z = rt(100,3))

DT3 <- data.table::data.table( a = list(DT1,DT2))
```

In a simple `DT1`, I know by using

```
DT1[, x %*% t(x)]
```

can ouput a matrix.

However, when `DT1,DT2` are wrapped in `DT3`, if I want to compute `x %*% t(z)`, how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: I tried ```DT3[, DT1$x %*% t(DT2$z)]``` and it might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` column with `lapply`, extract the dataset first column and apply the `%*%`

```
DT3[, lapply(a, function(u) u[[1]] %*% t(u[[1]]))]
```

---

If the OP wanted to do this based on extracting the `list` elements

```
DT3[, a[[1]]$x %*% t(a[[2]]$z)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try `Map` + `tcrossprod` within `DT3` like below

```
DT3[, do.call(tcrossprod, Map(`[[`, a, c("x", "z")))]
```